# Using Exclude/Intersect in the same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have this table:

```
Line Group
1      A 
2      A1
3      A2
4      A2
5      ALA
```

i wanna make a query that selects only the lines that contain a,a1,a2 but not the one named ALA

i tried a query like this:

select linea from table where group like'%A%'

Except

select linea from table where group ='ALA'

But didnt worked what can i do to get the data i need?

Ty in advance

Comment: `select linea from table where group like'%A%' and group not like 'ALA'`

Comment: why not just `select * from table where group <> 'ALA'`

Comment: @SQLChao Because there are more than these in my real table

Comment: Does Giorgos' answer fix you problem?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i tried your way but it still gets everything else in the table

Comment: I used this: select linea from table where (group = A or group =A1 or group = A2) and this worked but im not sure if i should use this since is not that efficent